# ERC 20 - very large balance created on a wallet

Tags: tokens, balances

I deployed an ERC20 at this address: [0x60c56fb23dc18c719491759b6c40cd46e502fcbd](https://etherscan.io/token/0x60c56fb23dc18c719491759b6c40cd46e502fcbd)

One of the addresses I own got a huge balance (more then the token supply) couple of days back. The address is: [0x27c36795f8d126b541d891cb9b1c10e57eb79372](https://etherscan.io/address/0x27c36795f8d126b541d891cb9b1c10e57eb79372)

Not sure how this happened - is it possible to trace the transaction that created the balance?

Here is my contract code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ERC20 Token, with the addition of symbol, name and decimals and assisted
// token transfers
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
contract ECHCoin  {

    string public symbol;
    string public name;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint public _totalSupply;
    address payable owner;
    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
    event Redeem(address indexed tokenOwner,  uint tokens);
    uint8 public returnFraction;
    uint public price;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    constructor() public {
        symbol = "ECH";
        name = "Eth Club";
        decimals = 8;
        _totalSupply = 30000000000000000;
        balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        owner = msg.sender;
        returnFraction = 72;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Total supply
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get the token balance for account tokenOwner
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Transfer the balance from token owner's account to to account
    // - Owner's account must have sufficient balance to transfer
    // - 0 value transfers are allowed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = (balances[msg.sender]- tokens);
        balances[to] = (balances[to] +  tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Token owner can approve for spender to transferFrom(...) tokens
    // from the token owner's account
    //
    // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md
    // recommends that there are no checks for the approval double-spend attack
    // as this should be implemented in user interfaces 
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Transfer tokens from the from account to the to account
    // 
    // The calling account must already have sufficient tokens approve(...)-d
    // for spending from the from account and
    // - From account must have sufficient balance to transfer
    // - Spender must have sufficient allowance to transfer
    // - 0 value transfers are allowed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = (balances[from] - tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = (allowed[from][msg.sender] - tokens);
        balances[to] = (balances[to] + tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Returns the amount of tokens approved by the owner that can be
    // transferred to the spender's account
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Token owner can approve for spender to transferFrom(...) tokens
    // from the token owner's account. The spender contract function
    // receiveApproval(...) is then executed
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    function approveAndCall(address spender, uint tokens, bytes memory data) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() { // Modifier
        require(
            msg.sender == owner,
            "Only owner can call this."
        );
        _;
    }

    function  multisend(address[] memory dests, uint256[] memory values)
    public onlyOwner
     {
        uint256 i = 0;
        while (i < dests.length) {
            balances[owner] = (balances[owner]- values[i]);
            balances[dests[i]] = (balances[dests[i]] +  values[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    event Investment(uint amount, address from);

    function() external payable {
        msg.sender.transfer(mul(msg.value, returnFraction)/100);
        emit Investment(msg.value, msg.sender);

    }

    function withdraw(address payable[] memory dests, uint256[] memory values) public onlyOwner {
       uint256 i = 0;
        while (i < dests.length) {
            dests[i].transfer(values[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // Gas optimization: this is cheaper than requiring 'a' not being zero, but the
        // benefit is lost if 'b' is also tested.
        // See: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/pull/522
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

        return c;
    }

    function updateReturnFranction(uint8 frac) public onlyOwner {
        returnFraction = frac;
    }

    function updatePrice(uint newPrice) public onlyOwner {
        price = newPrice; 
    }

    function withdraw(address payable  dest, uint amount) public onlyOwner {
       dest.transfer(amount);   
    }

    function kill() public {
        if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code for the contract.

Answer (score 2):

In function `transfer`:

```
balances[msg.sender] = (balances[msg.sender] - tokens);
```

You are not verifying `balances[msg.sender] >= tokens`.

And so when `balances[msg.sender] < tokens`, the unsigned value of `balances[msg.sender] - tokens` will typically be huge.

For example, consider the following case:

- `balances[msg.sender] == 0`
- `tokens == 1`

Then `balances[msg.sender] - tokens == 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

When stored into `int256`, this value is interpreted as "minus 1", which is what you'd expect the result of `0 - 1` to be. But when stored into `uint256`, this value is interpreted as "2 to the power of 256 minus 1".